# Тревоги для привлечения внимания модераторов на вопросах, не нарушающих правила

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, тревоги

Если посмотреть [справку по тревогам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), то тревоги нужно использовать, если:

1. **Необходимо внимание модератора ♦**.
2. Ответ не является ответом (включая ответы-ссылки).
3. Сообщение очень низкого качества (то есть никакая улучшающая правка не спасет сообщение).
4. Не соответствует тематике сайта, не являтеся вопросом, слишком специфичный, не конструктивный, повтор вопроса.
5. Спам (например, реклама)
6. Оскорбительный, агрессивный или сообщение содержит приступы изливания ненависти.

**5 из 6** причин про нарушение правил или неподходящий контент.

Бывает, что необходимо привлечь внимание модератора к тредам по синонимизации меток или для добавления меток вроде [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) или [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be). Сегодня в чате [была дана рекомендации](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46849545#46849545) по использованию тревог для этих вещей. Но, насколько я помню, недавняя автоматизации по детектированию "спасиб" в комментариях была направления на снижение количества тревог в очереди модераторов, в частности.

Так что, нормально ли использовать тревоги на вопросах для привлечения внимания модераторов к вопросам (при этом контент не нарушает правил и т.п.)?

Comment: Имхо, нормально. Куда удобнее, чем когда мне ссылку кидают.

Comment: @NickVolynkin но это попадает в очередь **всем** модераторам. К тому же, это не критические запрос, который следует обработать моментально.

Comment: Например, на Мете популярна тревога «поставьте метку [meta-tag:статус-завершено]». Она не попадает в этот список, но пользу приносит.

Comment: @NickVolynkin хм, спасибо. Буду тогда использовать)